# Windows 8.1 install restarts into setup

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, installation, reboot

My laptop is Samsung ativ book 6 and I'm installing windows 8.1 (64 bit) on it.
I made bootable usb, set bios to boot from it. Did setup, removed all partitions and made one partitions (system partition came with it).

Installation began and when the whole process reached "Finishing" part, installation restarted. But it didn't restart to complete installation it actually restarted me back to the begining of the setup.

I switched boot options back to my HDD (which I shouldn't have to do as far as I know) and windows 8.1 seemingly installed correctly. The problem occurs when I have to update the system it always fails/completes never ends actually.

The main questions is: How to make sure my installation completes properly, without restarting back to the begining of setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pull the USB stick out when it reboots. You can leave the boot options permanently set as USB/DVD/[floppy, lol]/HD & it will only start from other than the HD if there's a bootable device present. On install, boot from stick til it reboots, pull the stick, done.

Comment: That seems like a brute force and I'm not sure how's that different from me manually switching boot option from usb to hdd. In my experience (installing win7 not win 8 or 8.1) after reboot, installation usually does bit more "installing".

Comment: before it goes 'beep' it's not even fully aware there *is* a USB port. The installer should be smart enough to switch over, but not always. If it really wanted the stick, it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your disk partitions are in mbr or gpt. If its mbr then windows 8.1 wont recognise and will load set up window again. To convert mbr to gpt follow following procedure

1. While at partition window during set up press shift+F10 to start terminal
2. Then type diskpart
3. Type list disk (it will show all disk attached but select the Main pc hdd, in my case it was disk 0)
4. Type select disk (your hdd no)
5. Then type clean
6. Final step type convert gpt
7. Close the terminal